# Integrating GSL library into iPhone project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to integrate the GSL GNU library into my iPhone app. I copied all the files into my Xcode project but they give me the error. I don't know why this error comes.

Please help me to solve this.

Errors Log

```
/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find2d.c:20:10: In file included from /Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find2d.c:20:

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:24:34: Unknown type name 'size_t'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:27:13: Unknown type name 'size_t'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:27:61: Unknown type name 'size_t'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:29:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'size_t'; did you mean 'sizeof'?

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:29:10: Use of undeclared identifier 'i_linear'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:29:20: Use of undeclared identifier 'lower'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:29:27: Use of undeclared identifier 'upper'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:29:34: Use of undeclared identifier 'mid'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:46:5: Use of undeclared identifier 'i_linear'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:46:17: Use of undeclared identifier 'size_t'; did you mean 'sizeof'?

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:49:18: Use of undeclared identifier 'i_linear'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:49:41: Use of undeclared identifier 'i_linear'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:51:12: Use of undeclared identifier 'i_linear'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:58:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'upper'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:59:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'lower'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:61:10: Use of undeclared identifier 'upper'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:61:18: Use of undeclared identifier 'lower'

/Users/manas/Desktop/DerivativeApp/gsl-1.9 2/histogram/find.c:63:7: Use of undeclared identifier 'mid'

Too many errors emitted, stopping now.
```

Comment: please describe clear....